# Regex pattern for validation where 2 sections vary in length interdependently

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to workout a Regex pattern for validating a string that consists of 2 parts that vary in length but the overall length remains the same.

Overall length = 7 
start section alpha characters only 1-3 characters
end section 4-6 digits

combinations  1 Alpha + 6 digits or 2 Alpha + 5 digits or 3 Alpha + 4 digits.
In the second and third option the first character is allowed to be a space.

What I have so far is  ^(?:([\sA-Z][A-Z]{2})(\d{4})|[\sA-Z]A-Z|A-Z)$
Can that be simplified?
How can I have and optional Alpha character at the end?

Comment: Regular expressions aren't necesarily the best solution for everything. This seems like an example where it would be easier to get the two segments and then see if the total length is 7.

Comment: @Barmar - this is probably a perfect problem to use regular expressions on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a look ahead to assert the overall length and a negative look ahead to prevent the "space digit" start:

```
^(?=.{7}$)(?! \d) ?[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\d{4,6}$
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/wiq7D7cXJv) with several edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
 # (?i)^(?=.{7}$)(?:[a-z]{1,3}|[ ][a-z]{2,3})\d{4,6}[a-z]?$

 (?i)                     # Case independent
 ^                        # BOL
 (?= .{7} $ )            # 7 chars total

 (?:
      [a-z]{1,3}          # 1 to 3 alpha
   |  
      [ ] [a-z]{2,3}      # or, space plus 2 to 3 alpha
 )

 \d{4,6}                  # 4 to 6 digits
 [a-z]?                   # optional alpha char
 $                        # EOL
```

Comment: Thanks that works well.  I didn't know can assert the max length in that way.  One never stops learning.